# VSCode syntax highlighting: Is it possible to highlight a partial code snippet of an embedded language?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to write a VSCode extension for syntax highlighting. The target is a template language that embeds some 'c' code.

I have tried the 'embeddedLanguages' keyword from the VSCode doc, but it works only if the embedded code is well formed (e.g. comments closed)

Here is an example of the language. The delimitor '%' allows to switch between template mode and 'c' code:

```
#include "includeFile.h"
/*----------------------------------------------------
 * Resource descriptor of resource % !resource::NAME %
 * Tasks which use this resource :
 *
 * %
foreach task in resource::TASKUSAGE
do
  !task::VALUE
between
%
 * %
end foreach
```

this template code generates some c code, replacing the 'resource::NAME' in the generated file, and using a foreach loop (the '!' prints a var from template engine to generated c code)

I tried to use the 'embeddedLanguages', but it seems to not work if the 'c' code is not well formed: here the '%' to get back to the template language is located inside a comment block.

The result is not as expected, I do not get out of the 'c' mode!

[image: bad syntax highlighting]

It works correctly if I do not switch back to the template inside a comment: here, the '%' is well interpreted and I can get back to the template language mode.

[image: syntax highlighting ok here.]

Is it possible to highlight a partial code snippet of an embedded code?

The description in 'package.json':

```json
    "grammars": [
    {
      "language": "gtl",
      "scopeName": "source.gtl",
      "path": "./syntaxes/gtl.tmLanguage.json",
      "embeddedLanguages": {
        "meta.embedded.block.template.c": "c"
      }
    }
```

the language file:

```json
        "templates": {
            "contentName": "meta.embedded.block.template.c",
            "begin": "%",
            "end":"%",
            "beginCaptures": {
                "0": {"name": "punctuation.separator.template.open.gtl"}
            },
            "endCaptures": {
                "0": {"name": "punctuation.separator.template.close.gtl"}
            },
            "patterns": [
                {"include": "source.c"}
            ]
        }
```

regards,